# pl sql replace multiple values in sequence

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 2 columns in a table named `Query` and `Values`.

**Query :**

```
insert into 
tbl_details(CName,Line,Type,Command,Rule,Client_ID,Site_ID,SName) 
values (l_Name,:l_Line,:l_Type,:l_Command,:l_Rule,:l_Client_ID,:l_Site_ID,l_Name)
```

**Values :** `#1(2):20 #2(1):H #3(2):IF #4(27):FA - RETAIN OLD MASTER DATA #5(0):  #6(0):`

CName and SName use same value `Manu`.

I want to replace binded vars with values in next columns to get executable query.

**What i want:**
I want to write a procedure which get values from both columns of table to make a query and execute that query.

```
insert into address_MP (CName,Line,Type,Command,Rule,Client_ID,Site_ID,SName) 
values ('Manu','20','H','IF','FA - RETAIN OLD MASTER DATA','','Manu')
```

Comment: Change your design, it looks like a bad way to do things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option, which converts both query `VALUES` clause, as well as *values* themselves into rows - each in its own cursor loop, pairing bind variable and its value via their row number. `CHR(39)` is a single quote.

As the table most probably doesn't contain a single row (is it identified by some ID? You never told us), you'll have to adjust it, otherwise it won't work properly.

**Test table:**

```
SQL> select * from test;

QUERY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C_VALUES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
insert into
tbl_details(CName,Line,Type,Command,Rule,Client_ID,Site_ID,SName)
values (l_Name,:l_Line,:l_Type,:l_Command,:l_Rule,:l_Client_ID,:l_Site_ID,l_Name
)
#1(2):20 #2(1):H #3(2):IF #4(27):FA - RETAIN OLD MASTER DATA #5(0):  #6(0):


SQL> set serveroutput on
```

**Code & the result:**

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_query   test.query%TYPE;
  3     l_name    VARCHAR2 (30) := 'Manu';
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT query INTO l_query FROM test;
  6
  7     -- bind variables in QUERY
  8     FOR cur_l
  9        IN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY lvl) rn, res l_val
 10              FROM (    SELECT LEVEL lvl,
 11                               REGEXP_SUBSTR (res,
 12                                              '[^,]+',
 13                                              1,
 14                                              LEVEL)
 15                                  res
 16                          FROM (SELECT SUBSTR (query, INSTR (query, 'values')) res
 17                                  FROM test)
 18                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (res, ':') + 1)
 19             WHERE SUBSTR (res, 1, 1) = ':')
 20     LOOP
 21        -- values in VALUES
 22        FOR cur_v
 23           IN (SELECT rn, TRIM (SUBSTR (res, INSTR (res, ':') + 1)) c_val
 24                 FROM (    SELECT LEVEL rn,
 25                                  REGEXP_SUBSTR (t.c_values,
 26                                                 '[^#]+',
 27                                                 1,
 28                                                 LEVEL)
 29                                     res
 30                             FROM test t
 31                       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (t.c_values, '#'))
 32                WHERE rn = cur_l.rn)
 33        LOOP
 34           l_query :=
 35              REPLACE (l_query,
 36                       cur_l.l_val,
 37                       CHR (39) || cur_v.c_val || CHR (39));
 38        END LOOP;
 39     END LOOP;
 40
 41     -- Put Manu into l_Name
 42     l_query := REPLACE (l_query, 'l_Name', CHR (39) || l_name || CHR (39));
 43
 44     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_query);
 45  END;
 46  /
insert into
tbl_details(CName,Line,Type,Command,Rule,Client_ID,Site_ID,SName)

values ('Manu','20','H','IF','FA - RETAIN OLD MASTER DATA','','','Manu')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: what is t.c_values?

Comment: My "test" table (whose alias - in my example - is "t") has two columns: "query" and "c_values", because "values" is an invalid identifier (i.e. a *reserved word*) - you can't name a column "values", unless you enclose it into double quotes (which is something I refuse to do).